# Brick identification - two thin arches

Tags: part-identification

Can any one ID the red arch with the baby in it?
[image: two thin arches]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On bricklink that part is known as a [Red Wedge 4 x 3 Open with Cutout and 4 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47755&name=Wedge%204%20x%203%20Open%20with%20Cutout%20and%204%20Studs&category=%5BWedge%5D#T=C&C=5) and has item number 47755.

[image]

The build in the picture appears to be a custom build (I couldn't find an official set that includes it).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, yeah it’s a custom build, I have a cargo bike so wanted to replicate it for a build! Thank you again